# Using RoboSpice for asynchronus threading

Tags: android, multithreading, asynchronous, robospice

I am trying to use RoboSpice for my Android app but I am getting very confused with the documentation.

Basically, I would like to implement only an asynchronous service in the background of the app which does not get destroyed when the activity is changed etc for a thread that I run, much like the infographic that they have shown [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stephanenicolas/robospice/master/gfx/RoboSpice-InfoGraphics.png). How would I do this? I have a base activity so I have added the SpiceService to the onStart() and onStop() functions as instructed but I am unsure what to use as the custom SpiceService itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RoboSpice is designed to be tied to Android's activity lifecycle, so stopping the `SpiceService` between `Activity` changes is normal. The component that remains persistent between activities is its cache.
You can try, however, holding a `SpiceService` active throughout your app lifecycle by tying it to your `Application` context, but that [is not recommended](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice/issues/211).

About the other part of your question (what custom `SpiceService` to use), you should probably check [the offline example](https://github.com/octo-online/RoboSpice-samples/tree/release/robospice-sample-core-offline).

Comment: Thank you. In the end I just found it easier to tie the thread to the application layer rather than the activity layer which is all I need really in this example